# How to extend where MVC looks for views

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I an application that has a concept of discrete modules. These modules will live in Modules folder.  Each module will have a folder under this Modules folder.  These module folders will then have a Controllers and Views folder under them, very similar to how Areas work.

I would like to extend/change the search locations that are searched so that when my module controllers return a view the new locations will be searched.

I am thinking this will need to involve a custom ViewEngine, but I am uncertain of the specifics.  Is there a specific viewengine I can extend, or do I need to write a new one from scratch.

Is writing a custom view engine the right way to go, or is there a better route?

Comment: It is possible to have areas in separate projects and even separate solutions. It is also possible to have areas in a virtual directory pointing to a folder not within the base applications tree, but with their own bin folder. This is similar to what we have in our enterprise website. We have it in ASP.Net Forms, but I've written an implementation for MVC3 with areas. I would share it with you if I wasn't at home right now. The key is the AssemblyResolve event in the appdomain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am thinking this will need to involve a custom ViewEngine

[Correct thinking](http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/archive/2011/06/27/view-engine-with-dynamic-view-location.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of extending a specific view engine you can implement a view engine wrapper, that way your custom logic for locating views can work with multiple view engines. That's how [MvcCodeRouting](http://mvccoderouting.codeplex.com/) works, by temporarily replacing the controller value in `controllerContext.RouteData.Values`, so when a location format is used (such as `~/Views/{1}/{0}.aspx`) you can inject into those placeholders your custom location.