# Change the Location of the Controller inside the Project structure

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I found [this Post (How to extend where MVC looks for views)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7408596/how-to-extend-where-mvc-looks-for-views) about changing the location of the View.

I was wondering if there's something similar for changing the location of the controller.

I just want to change the location of the class inside project and don't want to affect the url.

For example Instead of placing the Controller into

```
MyMvcProject\Controllers\
                      MyController1.cs 
                      MyController2.cs 
                      MyController3.cs
```

I want to achieve  something like

```
MyMvcProject\MyGroup1\
                      MyController1.cs
                      MyController2.cs

MyMvcProject\MyGroup2\
                      MyController3.cs
```

and also support Areas:

```
MyMvcProject\Areas\MyGroup3\
                      MyController4.cs
```

Is it possible to achieve this? And if yes, where can I find documentation about it?

Comment: I really hate to post this kind of response, but you probably shouldn't be attempting this.  There would be no real purpose, would there?  Maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: I think you have not tested before asking the question. MVC does not care where the controller and models are located. You need use a custom factory when you don't want controller suffix or parameter less constructor. See, this link, http://forums.asp.net/p/1633844/4216014.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do what you want, and it doesn't require any special configuration, because ASP.NET MVC does not care about where you put your controllers. First, controllers are located using reflection, so the name of the folder where you put your controllers is irrelevant. Controllers are searched by type name and optionally by namespace (for disambiguation). You can even have controllers in separate projects/assemblies. As long as the controller ends up in an assembly in the `bin` folder then it's searchable by the framework.

Comment: +1 -this was what i was going to answer here.. controllers are compiled into the bin dll file and thus are located by type. views on the other hand are served from within the folder structure and thus must be easily located by convention dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above, you'll need to create a controller factory to support your custom resolution. Here's an example:

http://develoq.net/2010/custom-controller-factory-in-asp-net-mvc/

Answer (score 1):

As others have already stated you need to do one of the following:

1. Derive from `IControllerFactory` interface and provide an implementation of the `CreateController` and `ReleaseController` methods.
2. Derive from `DefaultControllerFactory` and override the default behaviours.

Here are some links to get you started:

- [Custom controller factory in ASP.Net](http://www.keyvan.ms/custom-controller-factory-in-asp-net-mvc)
- [Inside the ASP.NET MVC Controller factory](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/Inside-the-ASP-NET-MVC-Controller-Factory.aspx)
- [Dive deep into MVC - IControllerFactory](http://mgolchin.net/posts/18/dive-deep-into-mvc-icontrollerfactory)

Also, if you're willing to spend a bit of money I would also recommend the book **Pro ASP.NET MVC 3 Framework** as this explains almost every aspect of how the MVC framework can be customised (including an example on how to create a custom controller factory - the source code for which can be freely downloaded from the publishers website).

Answer (score 0):

I think it is impossible to do this. ASP.NET MVC have defined the convention that we have to follow.
Controllers are in Controllers folder, views are in Views{ControllerName}\

Comment: Well it's possible to change the View Location as described in my posted link. So I hope it's also possible for the controller.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you cannot change the convention unless you create your own ControllerFactory.

If you really want to do that, just implement IControllerFactory interface (or try to derive from DefaultControllerFactory).

Then your Application_Start register your controller factory using ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory method.

Look at the ControllerFactory documentation and to the MVC source code for details.

Comment: Willing to do that, but didn't find any documentation about it.

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking and what your example shows are two different things; depending on which one you want to achieve, you may or may not need to do any work.

There are two requirements for a class to be a controller in the MVC Framework:

1. It has to have a class name of *Name* + "Controller"
2. It has to have a parameterless public constructor.

Your sample "normal" MVC layout is actually not valid:

```
MyMvcProject\Controllers\
                      MyController1.cs 
                      MyController2.cs 
                      MyController3.cs
```

Those classes wouldn't be found by MVC because they don't have the correct name, regardless of which folder they are in.

If all you want to do is change the namespace/folder names, that "just works", assuming you name them the same as the appropriate route segment(s):

```
MyMvcProject\MyGroup1\
                      Page1Controller.cs
                      Page2Controller.cs
MyMvcProject\MyGroup2\
                      Page3Controller.cs
MyMvcProject\Areas\Area1\
                      Area1Page1Controller.cs
```

[This walkthrough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee671793%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) (written for MVC 2 but works just as well in MVC3) shows you how to support Areas with the default controller behavior.

If you actually want to name them `SomethingController1` or `SomethingElseController5`, or otherwise change the route -> classname mappings, then you *do* need to implement a custom `ControllerFactory`, and inject it into the MVC pipeline.

There are plenty of examples on the web on how to do this, including [the one posted earlier](http://develoq.net/2010/custom-controller-factory-in-asp-net-mvc/).